# What daily events can I do in Pokemon X/Y

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In some cities there are people who give you items (such as berries) for answering a question correctly. They also tell me to come back tomorrow to win again.

Is there a list of which people do this? I remember early in the game you get something for showing someone a type of pokemon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Boutiques** - Every day the items in the boutiques changes. These are random changes so you have to visit them frequently to find something you might want.

**Hotels** -  NPCs moved around to different hotels each day. But their is a lady that gives you a ribbon on different days.

Saturday - Cyllage City - Snooze Ribbon
Sunday - Courmarine City - Smile Ribbon
Monday - Ambrette Town - Alert Ribbon
Tuesday - Camphier Town - Shock Ribbon
Wednesday - Geosenge Town - Downcast Ribbon

**Cafes** - Going to different cafes each day, you can meet people that will show you different pokemon to fill up your pokedex.

**Lumiose City** - In Lumiose City there are 3 different events, you can participate in the Lotto ID. This is the daily lottery drawing like in prior games. The more Pokemon you have traded with different OT numbers, the better chances you have to win better prizes. Go to Richissme Hotel and participate in different jobs to earn money. And go to Cafe Action to get a new statement for your PR video.

**Camphrier City** - There is a house northwest to the fountain, a man is inside who asks to see a certain type of Pokemon. Show him that type and he will give you a choice of berries: Cheri, Chesto, Pecha, Rawst, and Aspear.

**Ambrette Town** - Outside of the fossil lab, there is a "punk" looking guy who will trade any one of your PokeBalls for a Dive Ball.

**Cyllage City** - Next door to the Pokemon Center, there is a man who will massage one Pokemon per day to increase happiness.

**Courmarine City** - There are 3 different things you can do here each day. 1 - Down by the stands where you can buy the incense, the second stand has a berry you can take. 2 - For only 4 days, there is a girl who will quiz you to get 4 different TM's, she is near the coastal side of the city. 3 - After defeating the Elite Four, Tierno will ask to see a pokemon with a certain move, show him it and he will give you a heart scale.

**Geosenge Town** - Trevor will be here after you defeat the Elite four. He will ask if you captured a certain pokemon and tell you if it has a mega evolution.

**Laverre City** - There are 2 different people that ask to see Pokemon of different sizes, they are near the east side of town. You can get Poke Dolls for showing them the correct Pokemon.

**Anister Dial** - The only time you can find certain Mega Stones is from 8-9pm. You have to go to Anistar's sundial to after you beat the elite four and get the absolite from your rival. You will speak to the professor to start this feature.

**Anister City** - Go inside the Pokemon center at different times throughout each day. There is a woman who will give you a new TM each time.

**Route 18 Inverse Battle** - You can fight the psychic inver guy each day in an inverse battle. After a few wins he will start giving you berries.

**Kiloude City** - Last but not least... fight your rival.

Comment: I went to Ambrette town today (Monday) and received the Alert Ribbon from the lady there, not the Shock Ribbon.

Comment: And confirmed that today (Tuesday) I got the Shock Ribbon, so I'm assuming those were just accidentally switched.

Comment: So I see the Anister Dial glowing, but how do I know where to go?

Answer (score 0):

In Ambrette Town you can get a Health Wing each day if you show a woman in the house to the left of the 'punk' guy who gives you a dive ball, a pokemon with a certain Speed.

Answer (score 0):

In Laverre town in the house behind the pokemon center you can get the effort ribbon, a ribbon awarded to a pokemon for being an exceptionally hard worker, I'm not Sure if she gives you another ribbon on  a different day because I just got that one :3

Comment: You get one each time you show a Pokemon fully trained and it's not dependent on the day...